# How to solve Error when creating executable with Nuitka: No module named 'kivy.weakmethod?

Tags: python, kivy, nuitka

I'm having trouble trying to compile a simple Python program that uses the Kivy framework into an executable using Nuitka. I used these two commands:

```
nuitka --mingw64 --follow-imports Tivy3.py 
python -m nuitka --plugin- enable=kivy --standalone your_script.py
```

When I try to run the already compiled program, I get the following error:

> [ERROR ] [Clock ] Unable to import kivy._clock. Have you perhaps
> forgotten to compile kivy? Kivy contains Cython code which needs to be
> compiled. A missing kivy._clock often indicates the Cython code has
> not been compiled. Please follow the installation instructions and
> make sure to compile Kivy Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\Users\oliveira pc2\anaconda3\envs\nuitikavirtual\Tivy3.py",
> line 23, in <module> from kivy. app import App File
> "C:\Users\oliveira
> pc2\anaconda3\envs\nuitikavirtual\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py",
> line 417, in <module kivy.app> from kivy.base import runTouchApp,
> async_runTouchApp , stopTouchApp File "C:\Users\oliveira
> pc2\anaconda3\envs\nuitikavirtual\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py",
> line 28, in <module kivy.base> from kivy.clock import Clock File "C
> :\Users\oliveira
> pc2\anaconda3\envs\nuitikavirtual\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py",
> line 466, in <module kivy.clock> from kivy._clock import
> CyClockBase, ClockEvent, FreeClockEvent, File "kivy_clock .pyx", line
> 10, in init kivy._clock ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'kivy.weakmethod'

**What I've done so far.**
Here's a rundown of what I've done so far, plus research on the error.
I created a virtual environment called "nuitikavirtual" using Conda.
I installed Nuitka within this environment.
I copied my script (Tivy3.py) into this environment.
I installed Kivy and other required dependencies in that environment

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to run your script before you compile it? Everything should be fully functional before running Nuitka commands.